# Store resultset of query in in some structure and then update some table when fetching rows from temp reultset

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am working on Oracle stored procedure. I run a query in which I create partitions and create a new column with a numeric value. I need to store this result somewhere and use it as a source when I am updating my original table. Something like this:

select x,y,.. from tableA, (rownum() over partiton by x)new_col where ...(list of conditions)
....
loop condition
update tableA where new_col= (some numeric value of loop var)
...

I tried using cursor and bulk collecting the output of first query into a variable, but when I run the loop I will have to parse over single row of the cursor. I don't want that...I want the update to run over multiple rows in the original table. This is possible if I simply run my update query in the loop but the where conditions and calculation of the new column in each iteration doesn't seem efficient.

Without creating a temp table ..is this possible? Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried yet?

Comment: Why do you need to "store" the results somewhere? Why can't you do **everything** in a single statement? Why do you need a procedure for this (stored or otherwise)? You should be able to do everything in plain SQL - it will almost surely be much more efficient than anything you can do in a procedure.

Comment: The stored procuedure is being used for some other functionality too. If the single statement is ran in every iteration wont be very efficient

Answer (score 0):

As the question is a bit ambigious, i have tried to replicate your scenario. Hope this helps. MERGE can suffice your problem as illustrated.

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA USING 
(SELECT X,Y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY 1 DESC) NEW_COL FROM TABLEB)b 
ON 
(tableA.col1 = tableB.col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET NEW_COL = b.NEW_COL;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had used merge too. But the thing is I have to loop until a condition becomes false. And the update statement depends on that particular iteration. I want to avoid that part in loop which can be calculated previously and stored. For example the rownum by partitioning doesnt need to to be re-calculated in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) to do such work. You can create a `RECORD` and the process your requirement. See an example below:

```
create or replace procedure proc
as 

-- This should have same columns as you are selecting from the query below.
type x is record ( col1 number,
                   col2 number,
                   .
                   .
                   .
                  );

type var is table of x index by pls_integer;

var1 var;

begin

    select x,y,..
    bulk collect into var1 
    from tableA, 
    (rownum() over partiton by x)new_col 
    where ...(list of conditions) .... ;


    for rec in 1..var1.count
    loop

      update tableA 
      where new_col= var1.col1 ;

    end loop;


end;
```